# Checkout Script failing with error as 403 session expired while performing checkout through JMEter

Tags: jmeter, checkout

I have recorded a script and performing the load test on the same but whenever it comes to billing address the script gets failed with error 403 session expired. The flow of my script is

```
launch application-->select any course-->Add course to cart-->login with valid cred-->enter card and billing address details (CC) or the third party-->click on place order--> get transaction successful message.
```

Whenever script reached to billing and address details page shows error as 403 sessions expired.causing following script failure

Please suggest. Performing checkout on Magento.

Comment: Are you sending cookies that are generated during Login? Add HTTP Cookie Manager and try. Check whether Cookies are sent or not using View Results Tree

Comment: @Naveen Cookies are sent as i have recorded script using blazemeter tool so HTTP Cookie manager is added by default. so what should i do next. and while performing checkout via CC no session ID is generated so that i can collect that through regEx and pass it through.

Comment: compare the Cookies sent by browser (F12 -> Network tab) and JMeter. There may be mismatch in number of cookies sent? Or any other header/body parameter which is responsible for session management. so, carefully compare the requests. Add screen shots of the request (from Browser & JMeter) .

Comment: Thanks @Naveen i can see that itksid and frontend are different rest of the data is same can you please add up more information to my knowledge so that i can move ahead and if you can guide me how to use regEx and where to use it means before which request i have to use it all that will be helpful

Comment: correlate those values and try. It is trial and error unless you are so sure what those parameters mean to the server.

Comment: any update on the progress?